# Proof of forbidden free electron-photon absortion using spacetime diagram

Tags: special-relativity

I'm trying to solve this exercise from the book "Modern Classical Physics" by Kip Thorne:

> Show, using spacetime diagrams and also using frame-independent calculations, that the law of conservation of 4-momentum forbids a photon to be absorbed by an electron

I managed to prove this using coordinates: choose the Lorent's frame in which the electron is at rest, in this frame its 4-momentum is simply $\vec{p_e}=(m,0,0,0)$ and let the photon be moving from left to right, so its 4-momentum is $\vec{p_\gamma}=(\epsilon,\epsilon,0,0)$. Using conservation of 4-momentum, after the absortion the 4-momentum of the electron should be $\vec{p_e} = (m+\epsilon,\epsilon,0,0)$, but this generates a contradiction, because for any massive particle we have that $\vec{p}^2= -m^2$, but if $\vec{p_e}^2=-m^2-2m\epsilon-\epsilon^2 +\epsilon^2=-m^2$, we conclude that $2m\epsilon=0$, so either the mass of the electron is zero or the energy of the photon is zero, contradiction!

My problem is, how can I prove that this reaction is forbidden using a spacetime diagram? I tried to draw one, but I can't see where the contradiction will arise from it.

Comment: The photon monentum is on the light cône, while the electron is inside the light cône, so they aren’t compatible.

Comment: @Cham what do you mean with "they aren't compatible"?

Comment: When Kip says "frame independent calculation", it means you can't use the rest frame of the electron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw some electron worldline inside the past light cone suddenly transforming into a photon line (on the light cone) and another electron worldline inside the future light cone, you should notice that it doesn't satisfy both energy and momentum conservation (***bold*** symbols are four-vectors):
$$\tag{1}
\boldsymbol{p}_A = \boldsymbol{p}_B + \boldsymbol{k}.
$$
This equation could be written as this:
$$\tag{2}
\boldsymbol{p}_A - \boldsymbol{p}_B = \boldsymbol{k}.
$$
The four-vector $-\, \boldsymbol{p}_B$ could be interpreted as an electron moving to the past, in the past light cone.  Now draw the worldlines in the total momentum frame.  You should notice that there's a problem!

Also, take the invariant square of equation (2) ($\circ$ is the four-vector scalar product):
$$\tag{3}
p_A^2 + p_B^2 - 2 \,\boldsymbol{p}_A \circ \boldsymbol{p}_B = k^2 \equiv 0.$$
Then $p_A^2 = p_B^2 = m^2$ (the electron stays an electron!) so (3) reduces to
$$\tag{4}
m^2 = \boldsymbol{p}_A \circ \boldsymbol{p}_B.
$$
This equation cannot be true, unless $\boldsymbol{p}_A \equiv \boldsymbol{p}_B$ (which implies $\boldsymbol{k} = 0$, i.e no photon!)